# Adding javascript code that has both types of quotes ("/') in shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am trying to add some javascript code into my shiny app. The js code snippet below was provided by a data vendor to add on my website. The issue i am facing is, I can not bracket "script...script" in single or double quotes since there are both types of quotes inside the js script. Would anyone know how to embed this js script below into my shiny app? Thank you kindly.

JS Code:

```
 <script src="https://companyxyz.outseta.com/scripts/client/dist/outseta.profile.widget.min.js"
        data-popup-selector="a[href^='https://companyxyz.outseta.com/widgets/profile']"
        defer="defer"></script>
```

My Attempt:

```
tags$head(HTML('<script src="https://companyxyz.outseta.com/scripts/client/dist/outseta.profile.widget.min.js"
        data-popup-selector="a[href^='https://companyxyz.outseta.com/widgets/profile']"
        defer="defer"></script>'))
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: In javascript there are 3 types of quotes: " ' and `.

Try using the `` quotes.

Comment: @PascalK good to know, would i just sub the ' ' for ` ` and then use ' ' on either side of script?

Comment: You can nest ' and " inside `, so that should work.

Comment: You can use `\"`.

Comment: Or use `tags$script(......)` instead of `HTML('<script>......</script>')`.

Comment: hey guys thanks for reaching out. Using tags$script() alone did not work. My attempt actually did end up working. I just had to switch from tags$head to tags$body